# Nested vue js v-for from lodash groupby

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, lodash

I am grouping my data that fetch from database using lodash groupby like this

```
var vm = this
axios.get(this.buildURL())
.then(function(response) {
    Vue.set(vm.$data, 'model', response.data.model)
    vm.groupData = _.groupBy(vm.model.data,'categories')
})
.catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error)
})
```

and i got this result in groupData like this when i view it in vue extension on google chrome

```
groupData: object
 > news: Array[2]
   > 0: Object
     name: "test article"
   > 1: Object
     name: "test article 2"
 > entertainment: Array[1]   
   > 0: Object
     name: "test article 3"
```

and i think i just need to do nested v-for like this

```
<tr v-for="(items,index) in groupData">
    {{index}} // category name
     <tr v-if="items != null" v-for="item in items">
         <td>{{item.name}}</td> //article name
     </tr>
</tr>
```

but i got error in console

> app.js:5428 [Vue warn]: Property or method "items" is not defined on
>   the instance but referenced during render. Make sure to declare
>   reactive data properties in the data option.

why is it happening? where do i get wrong?

**update**
in html i want to create row grouping in table so what i want is like this

```
--------------------------------
name | created_at | updated_at |
--------------------------------
news //categori name
--------------------------------
test | 1/1/2017   | 2/1/2017   |
--------------------------------
test2| 1/1/2017   | 2/1/2017   |
--------------------------------
entertainment //categori name
--------------------------------
test| 1/1/2017   | 2/1/2017   |
--------------------------------
```

Comment: i am making row grouping in table, it is not tested yet... because that error

Comment: yes i warp it inside <template> //table html </template>

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Okay so after playing around with the html (since i already know what when wrong is just my html) i come up with this solution

```
<tbody v-for="(items,index) in groupData">
    <tr class="active border-double" v-if="isGroup">
      <td :colspan="thead.length"> // array for header, i just coun't how many header in the table to define colspan
        {{index}}
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr v-for="item in items" :item="item">
        <td>{{item.name}}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```